# (), (Nothing) and _ in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm playing with some lambdas, where `write` and `flush` are of type `Try[Unit]`. I get different types depending on what parameter I pass into the lambdas though:

```
val writeLambda: (Nothing) => Try[Unit] = _ => write
val flushLambda: () => Try[Unit] = () => flush
```

If the lambda is `_ => write`, I get a parameter type of `(Nothing)`, but if it is `()`, I get `()`. What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

> If the lambda is `_ => write`, I get a parameter type of `(Nothing)`

Not exactly. `_` acts as a (wildcard and ignored) parameter in the lambda expression `_ => write`, so it has to have some type, and of course it can be whatever you want it to be - from `Any` to `Nothing` in the [Scala class hierarchy](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified-types.html). Omitting the type will be a "Missing parameter type" error.

The empty parantheses in the other lambda expression `() => flush` imply that it's not taking any parameters, which is pretty much what the return type `() => Try[Unit]` implies.

```
import scala.util.Try

object TestObject {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val writeLambda: (Any => Try[Unit]) = { _ => write }
    val flushLambda: (() => Try[Unit]) = { () => flush }

    writeLambda(Map("one" -> Option(BigDecimal(1)))) // prints "write"
    writeLambda(List(1, 2, 3)) // prints "write"
    writeLambda(None) // prints "write"
    writeLambda(1) // prints "write"
    writeLambda() // prints "write"

    flushLambda() // prints "flush"
    flushLambda(None) // won't compile because "Too many arguments"
  }

  def write: Try[Unit] = Try(println("write"))
  def flush: Try[Unit] = Try(println("flush"))
}
```

Comparing to Java, the first one would be a regular Lambda expression where as the second one has a more specific idiom called [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) (if you will).